# JSP Template in other file - Spring Boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I'm making a web application in spring boot. I have a lot of views created in JSP, but every view has the same footer and the same menu. Of course I can just copy all menu and footer code and paste it to 30 JSP but I would like to do somethink like this: I have file in which I have something like that menu="HTML CODE WITH MENU", and then in JSP in body section I just put {menu}, and all HTML code is put inside JSP. When I want to change my menu I will just change its code in "menu" variable/string or whatever it will be, and menu in all JSP will change. I tried a few solutions for example with include but it doesn't work. I search scritly the solution I have mentioned. Has anybody got any ideas how I can do this ?

Comment: Short answer, use a JSP includes. Long answer - JSP is transpiled to a Java servlet and then compiled and run as a servlet - so every JSP is a servlet. This is rather ... messy. It's not really very good as a template engine - I would _strongly_ suggest you use [Thymeleaf](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) as recommended by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using JSP you can use the standard JSTL `<c:import>` tag as [explained here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). The other options would be to use `<%@ include @>` or `<jsp:include>`, either of them will work for local files:

```
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
<c:import url="footer.jsp" />
```

Comment: Yep, but it requires that the template JSP also has to have head tags and all hrefs to css because it doesnt inherite from main JSP which it is included in, and it caused that in browser after F12 you have double HEAD section in body for example, I have already tested it ;/

Comment: Without tags, css werent included in template, I did it the same way as it is presented in spring tutorials, but I must have different head section in all jsp, but this include instead of HTML file also loads head section from this template

Comment: Your link doesn't explain about `<c:import>` tag.